# two event listeners, to reload content, both rendered inside conditionals inside a function, yet one doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

I've simplified the code to handle the same function (handlestartbuttonpress) for simplicity and debugging sake. When the "start button" is pressed, everything works as expected, a short delay  before updating  the page and rendering the page with the content for "a". but on the "a" page, the option 2 div element should reload to the "b" page. but i get nothing.

I've tried different ways of calling the function including onclick rather than event listeners, same result.

```js
let score = 0;
let op1 = '';
let op2 = '';
let op3 = '';
let opc = '';
let nxt = '';

function reload(rp) {
  if (rp === '') {
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML =
      `<div id="startbuttoncontainer"><img id="startbutton" src='assets/startbutton.png' /></div>`;
  }
  if (rp === 'score') {
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML =
      `<span>Final Score<br/>${score}</span>`;
  }
  if (rp === 'a') {
    op1 = 'Red';
    op2 = 'Apple';
    op3 = 'Tree';
    opc = '2';
    nxt = 'b';
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML =
      `
        <div id="paperbg">
            <span id="score">Score: ${score}</span>
            <img id="obj"  src="assets/${rp}.png" />
        </div>

        <div id="opscontainer">
            <div id="op1" class="op">${op1}</div>
            <div id="op2" class="op">${op2}</div>
            <div id="op3" class="op">${op3}</div>
        </div>
        
    `;
  }
  if (rp === 'b') {
    op1 = 'Blue';
    op2 = 'Bunny';
    op3 = 'Banana';
    opc = '3';
    nxt = 'c';
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML =
      `
        <div id="paperbg">
            <span id="score">Score: ${score}</span>
            <img id="obj"  src="assets/${rp}.png" />
        </div>

        <div id="opscontainer">
            <div id="op1" class="op">${op1}</div>
            <div id="op2" class="op">${op2}</div>
            <div id="op3" class="op">${op3}</div>
        </div>
        
    `;
  }
}



function handlestartbuttonpress(p) {
  // document.getElementById('startbuttoncontainer').innerHTML =
  //  `<img id="startbuttonpressed" src='assets/startbuttondown.gif' />`;

  setTimeout(function() {
    reload(p);
  }, 1600);
}

reload('');

document.getElementById('startbutton').addEventListener("click", function() {
  handlestartbuttonpress('a');
});
document.getElementById('op2').addEventListener("click", function() {
  handlestartbuttonpress('b');
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html code you are using . Perhaps in the form of stack snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are adding the even listener too early.
SetTimeout make the `a` part render after 1600 ms while you are adding the event listener before `a` has rendered.
Thus `op2` element does not exist when you are adding the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate.

Here is a cleaner version

```js
let score = 0;
let op1 = '';
let op2 = '';
let op3 = '';
let opc = '';
let nxt = '';

const reload = (rp) => {
  console.log(rp)
  switch (rp) {
    case '':
      document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = `<div id="startbuttoncontainer"><img id="startbutton" src='assets/startbutton.png' alt="start"/></div>`;

      break;
    case 'score':
      document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = `<span>Final Score<br/>${score}</span>`;

      break
    case 'a':
      {
        op1 = 'Red';
        op2 = 'Apple';
        op3 = 'Tree';
        opc = '2';
        nxt = 'b';
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML =
        `
        <div id="paperbg">
            <span id="score">Score: ${score}</span>
            <img id="obj"  src="assets/${rp}.png" />
        </div>

        <div id="opscontainer">
            <div id="op1" class="op">${op1}</div>
            <div id="op2" class="op">${op2}</div>
            <div id="op3" class="op">${op3}</div>
        </div>
        
    `;
      }
      break;
    case 'b':
      {
        op1 = 'Blue';
        op2 = 'Bunny';
        op3 = 'Banana';
        opc = '3';
        nxt = 'c';
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML =
        `
        <div id="paperbg">
            <span id="score">Score: ${score}</span>
            <img id="obj"  src="assets/${rp}.png" />
        </div>

        <div id="opscontainer">
            <div id="op1" class="op">${op1}</div>
            <div id="op2" class="op">${op2}</div>
            <div id="op3" class="op">${op3}</div>
        </div>`;
        break;
      }
  }
};



const handlestartbuttonpress = (p) => {
  setTimeout(() => reload(p), 1600);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.id && tgt.id === 'startbutton') handlestartbuttonpress('a');
    else if (tgt.id && tgt.id === 'op2') handlestartbuttonpress('b');
  });

  reload('');

});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```